# I want to remove if else and want to use lookup or hashmap

Tags: python-3.x

i want to get rid of if else with lookup or hashmap.

currently I am using below code.

```
if min<=60:
    print('The rating for time is 10')
elif 60<min<=120:
    print('The rating for time is 8.34')
elif 120<min<=180:
    print('The rating for time is 6.68')
elif 180<min<=240:
    print('The rating for time is 5.02')
elif 240<min<=300:
    print('The rating for time is 3.36')
else:
    print('The rating for time is 1.7')
```

Please help me get rid of is else.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the number to output follows a certain formula as it does in your question, you can simply calculate it.

Note that `min` is a built-in function in Python so you should avoid naming a variable as such. Using `minutes` instead in the following example:

```
import math

print(f'The rating for time is {10 - min(math.ceil(minutes / 60) - 1, 5) * 1.66:.3}')
```

Comment: FOR me it is showing the float object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap, or in the case of Python, a dictionary, only works for a finite number of possible inputs. You could substitute *this* sequence of if-else statements

```
if num == 60:
    print("sixty")
elif num == 120:
    print("one-twenty")
else:
    print("other")
```

with a dict. Because there's an "else" statement a defaultdict might be a good choice. You could use this as

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_choice = defaultdict(lambda: "other")
my_choice[60] = "sixty"
my_choice[120] = "one-twenty"
print(my_choice[30], my_choice[60]) #prints "other", "sixty"
```

In your case the inputs are ranges (`120<min<=180`) and not unique values, so a hashmap is not the right choice here.